# Creating Methods

Tags: c#, methods, console

I'm creating a text based RPG.  Can you help me create a method? I want to learn how to create a method so I don't have to copy paste the `"help"` `case` into every loop.

Here is what I want the method to do:

```
string command;
while (command != "exit game")
 {
    command=Console.ReadLine();

     switch(command){
     case (help):
        Console.WriteLine("List of useableverbs and nouns");
        break;
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("Invalidcommand");
        break;
      }
    }
```

Also, how can I set it up so that "exit game" exits the game?

**I started programming a few weeks ago**, so any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please take more care with your formatting in future. That was a mess to clean up!

Comment: I updated the post to make the questions more clear.  The fact that you showed us code tells us what you've tried and allows us to help you.  There's no need to explain "where you can do your own research" after you've shown what you have tried and explained where the problems are.  Be sure to ask more direct questions to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method:

```
void HandleCommand(string command)
{
    switch (command)
    {
        case (help):
           Console.WriteLine("List of useable verbs and nouns");
           break;
        default:
           Console.WriteLine("Invalid command");
           break;
    }
}
```

And to use it:

```
while (command != "exit game")
{
    command=Console.ReadLine();
    HandleCommand(command);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set this up as a do while in a [method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).  Methods create re-useable code.  This avoids the need to copy and paste the same logic.  Instead of copy pasting code, you simply call the method via (in this case):

`CheckCommand();`

The method can look like...

```
private static void CheckCommand()
{
    string command;
    do
    {
        command = Console.ReadLine();
        switch (command)
        {
            case ("help"):
                Console.WriteLine("List of useable verbs and nouns");
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid command");
                break;
        }
    }
    while (command != "exit game");

}
```

This is setup so if the user types in "exit game" the loop will exit.  on another note, one good way to extend this logic is to do a [case insensitive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.tolower%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a variable named help you'd want to put quotes around it. IE:

```
case("help"):
```

As written, typing 'exit game' should break the loop and close the console window if you put it in your case. It could be cleaner, like using constants instead of hard coded strings.

Answer (score 0):

In C# you create methods just like it looks like you would. Let's say you want to show your help text, then outside of any other method (Probably your main method), you'd write something along the lines of:

```
static void ShowHelp() {
    Console.WriteLine("This is some text. Enter some command!");
    var command = Console.ReadLine();
    //Do other things
}
```

And then whenever you want that text to show up, you'd call it with `ShowHelp()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Boolean variable in order to signal the end of the game to the loop. The command has to be queried within the loop and since the command is not known when the loop starts, I would put the loop condition at the end of the loop.

```
bool doExit = false;
do {
    string command = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
    switch (command) {
        case "exit":
        case "quit":
            doExit = true;
            break;
        case "otherCommand":
            HandleOtherCommand();
            break;
        case "?":
        case "h":
        case "help":
            PrintHelp();
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid command!");
            PrintHelp();
            break;
    } 
} while (!doExit);
```

Using a Boolean variable has the advantage that you can easily terminate the game when other conditions are met. For instance when the player has won or lost the game.

---

Now for the methods. You can place methods within the same source code (Program.cs) or create new classes. Within Program.cs you would write something like

```
private static void PrintHelp()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Valid commands:");
    Console.WriteLine("help, h, ?: Print this help.");
    Console.WriteLine("exit, quit: End this game.");
    Console.WriteLine("...");
}
```

Note that since the `Main` method is static, the other methods within this same class have to be static too. If you are creating other classes for the commands, you can choose, whether you want to create static classes or not. Static classes are just a place where you put methods.

```
static class GameCommands
{
     // The `public` modifier makes it visible to other classes.
    public static void PrintHelp()
    {
        ...
    }

    public static void SomeOtherCommand()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

You can call such methods with the `className.MethodName()` syntax.

```
GameCommands.PrintHelp();
```

If you have to store different states (like a score, for instance). It is appropriate to create non-static classes. You can kind of create copies of such classes called class instances or objects. This actually only copies the state of the class but not the method code. Non-static methods can act on this state (fields, properties).

```
class Player
{
    // Constructor. Initializes an instance of the class (an object).
    public Player (string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    // Property
    public int Score { get; private set; }

    // Property
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    // Instance method (non-static method) having a parameter.
    public void IncreaseScoreBy(int points)
    {
        Score += points;
    }

    public void PrintWinner()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The winner is {0} with a score of {2} points." Name, Score);
    }
}
```

You can use such a class like this

```
Player player1 = new Player("John"); // Pass an argument to the constructor.
Player player2 = new Player("Sue");

player1.IncreaseScoreBy(5);
player2.IncreaseScoreBy(100);

if (player1.Score > player2.Score) {
    player1.PrintWinner();
} else if (player2.Score > player1.Score)
    player2.PrintWinner();
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("The score is even!");
}
```

---

We used methods with no return value until now. This is signaled by the void keyword that replaces the return type.

```
void MethodWithNoReturnValue() { ... }
```

If you have a return value (i.e. your method is a function), you have to specify the return type. The `return` statement terminates the function and specifies the return value.

```
double Reciprocal(double x)
{
    return 1.0 / x;
}
```

You would call it like this within the same class

```
double y = Reciprocal(x);
```

or by prepending it with the object name or the class name if it was static.